# Équivalent français de « bad trip »

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, anglais

[Un article du monde](http://www.lemonde.fr/addictions/article/2016/05/31/retour-en-grace-de-la-mdma-la-drogue-de-l-amour_4929888_1655173.html) utilise la traduction littéral « **mauvais voyage** », qui paraît inappropriée. Google translate propose plutôt « **mauvais délire** » qui me semble plus fidèle à l'esprit original de l'expression.

J'ai toujours entendu « *bad trip* » utilisé tel quel, mais existe-il une tournure idiomatique en français ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

J'ai souvent entendu l'expression *bader* (aussi orthographié *badder*) dans ce genre de contexte :

> Oh ce que j'ai pris c'est puissant je suis en train de bader !

Où *bader* semble directement provenir de l'anglais "bad", évidemment.
Cependant c'est très très familier et je ne pense pas pouvoir le dire autre part qu'entre amis.

Dans un cadre plus formel, on peut parler d'*effets paniquants*, mais qui reste assez neutre quant à la source de la panique et qui n'a pas autant l'envergure traumatisante que relaie le *bad trip*.

Sinon je conseille de garder l'expression anglaise, qui est déjà dans le langage courant grâce notamment au [film éponyme](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_Bad_Trip), et qui sera comprise sans ambiguité .

Answer (score 1):

Je pense aussi que **Mauvais délire** est la traduction plus appropriée ici. **Mauvais voyage** fait vraiment Google Traduction pour le coup, et j'ai jamais vu **bad trip** traduit de cette façon.

L'expression est telle quelle sur [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bad_trip). C'est pas à prendre comme une vérité absolue, mais je pense que l'utilisation de **bad trip** en français n'est pas préjudiciable.

Answer (score 1):

Un des sens du mot *trip* en anglais :

> 5. slang (orig. U.S.).
>      a. A hallucinatory experience induced by a drug, esp. LSD
>      (OED)

Le mot voyage en français a-t-il ce sens ? Il semblerait que oui :

> − État d'hallucination provoqué par l'usage de la drogue, notamment du L.S.D. Synon. trip.Voyage narcotique; voyage à l'acide. *Les « voyages » auxquels la drogue nous invite risquent d'être de plus en plus pauvres et solitaires. Mais ce qui demeure, et qui est essentiel, c'est que ces « voyages » sont une manière de refuser une société invivable et de s'en évader* (R. Garaudy, L'Altération, Paris, R. Laffont, 1972, p. 40).
>   *Faire/tenter le voyage.* Se droguer. *Localisé d'abord en Nouvelle-Angleterre, en Californie et au Mexique, le culte du LSD ne cesse de se répandre. Aux États-Unis, il touche maintenant les lycéens, qui tentent le « voyage »: ainsi désigne-t-on l'expérience délirante* (L'Express, 25 avr. 1966, p. 89, col. 2). [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/voyage)

Donc, oui, le mot « voyage » avec le sens d'expérience hallucinogène est bien rentré dans la langue française depuis plusieurs décennies. *Trip* est aussi utilisé, mais surtout par les « jeunes » générations.

Le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (sld alain Rey) signale que «  voyage est utilisé au figuré (1966) à propos de l'état provoqué par l'absorption d’hallucinogènes en concurrence avec l'**anglicisme**<sup>*</sup> trip [...] »

Quelques emplois récents en contexte :

> Cette réaction, connue sous le nom de mauvais voyage (bad trip), s’accompagne de conduites susceptibles d’être dangereuses.([http://www.toxquebec.com](http://www.toxquebec.com/livre_drogues/fr/index_mescaline.html))
>
> Une telle expérience, parfois proche de la première, est aussi désignée sous le nom de "mauvais voyage". Une expérience psychédélique psychodynamique [...] (Michel Rosenzweig - *Drogues et civilisations. Une alliance ancestrale*, 2008)
>
> L'expérience psychédélique [...] se distingue des autres expériences psychotropiques par l'étroite relation entre l'état d'esprit du consommateur et le voyage qui en résulte.([wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drogue_psych%C3%A9d%C3%A9lique))
>
> Un voyage à l'acide comporte trois phases [...] ([infodrogues.be](http://www.infordrogues.be/index.php/produits/hallucinogenes-drogues-psychedeliques?id=152))
>
> [...] le voyage hallucinogène, la « planète » sous opiacés, le « high » de la cocaïne : autant de façons de modifier les perceptions de soi même et du monde, pouvant réaliser une « extase » au sens étymologique (Claude Olievenstein, *Toxicomanie et devenir de l'humanité*, 2001)
>
> [...] état amoureux déchiré,trauma affectif, perte brutale, voyage hallucinogène : nous voilà confronté non pas au vieux débat opposant le [...] (Gérard Pirlot, *Psychanalyse des addictions* - 2013)

<sup>* C'est moi qui souligne.</sup>

Comment: Je dirais plutôt que « voyage » est sorti de la langue française depuis plusieurs décennies. Les deux citations le mettent entre guillemets, pour traduire littérallement « *trip* ». J'ai déjà entendu « tripper » pour « délirer », mais jamais « voyager », ce ne serait pas compris.

Comment: @Gilles Sorti de la langue française ?

Comment: Bon, vu les citations récentes, effectivement on peut dire que le sens existe encore. Mais je ne l'ai jamais rencontré, alors que *trip* en anglais et même en français, si. Bizarre.